# How do I make topfit work with legion's "dual-wield" artifact weapons?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How do I make the topfit add-on work with "dual-wield" artifact weapons?  It keeps making a clicking sound once every second for five seconds as it tries to equip another item that it can't use!

Answer (score 1):

For each spec you have, do the following:

1. Change to the spec
2. Unequip the weapon
3. Open your character screen
4. Hold down alt and mouse-over your "main" weapon slot.  (If you're in a typical spec, this is your main hand; if you're in a tanking spec, it might be your off-hand.)
5. Check the box in the bottom left of the icon that represents your artifact weapon
6. Hold down alt and mouse-over your other weapon slot, what I'm calling the "non-main" weapon slot.
7. Check the box of the "place in bags" icon.

That should work.